# About a vectorial measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

We consider the measure space $\mathbb{N}$, with the counting measure, and $\lbrace{e_i\rbrace}$ the standard basis for $\ell^1$:

How can I prove that the function $\nu$ mapping each $B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ to $\nu(B)=\displaystyle\sum_{i\in B}\frac{1}{2^i}e_i$ defines a vectorial measure, with values in $\ell^1$?

How can we describe the space of integrable functions $L^1(\nu)$?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.